# getting Kusto table name for output of union *

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The Kusto operator `union *` gets all the tables from a database , but once the data is clubbed together , we have no way to tell which rows came from where. Is there a way to force `union *` to add a column to the output that will contain name of the table a specific row came from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `withsource` (see in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer))

[execute query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAyvNy8zPUyjPLMkozi8tSk61DUlMykn1S8xNVdBS4KpRKC7NzU0syqxKVUjOL80r0dBUSKpUQKgBqijJL1AwAomCFcQDALYdVg1RAAAA)

```
union withsource=TableName * 
| summarize count() by TableName 
| top 2 by count_
```